# Which will be optimal way? Creating different databases dynamically or creating tables in same database and link them with a foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, forum

I am creating a forum website using JSP and Servlet. I am having a confusion deciding that when a user creates a new account on my website, I should create a new database dynamically and specifically for that user that should contain his all data including his forum threads, profile, thread replies, etc. or I should use same database and create different tables like forumsThreads, userProfiles, etc. and link them with a foreign key. Which will be best way?

Comment: Why create different databases for each user? Why not just store the entries in the same table?

Comment: That's what am asking that creating a new database will lead to more than one connections at a time. Is it optimal? So what way is actually followed by other forum websites?? I want to know that.

Answer (score 2):

Create one database with multiple tables. Let me rephrase your question:

- when a user creates a new account on my website, I should create a new User record dynamically
- each time the user does something, I should create records in a number of tables that will store all his data including his forum threads, profile, thread replies, etc.
- all his data will be linked with foreign keys
- when another user creates another account, I can reuse all the programming logic and the database I used to process the first user.

Creating a whole new database per user is a big Anti-Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create databases or tables dynamically. Everything you consider creating a new table (or database) for probably should just be a record in a table (or multiple tables) containing a user_id column identifying the user this record applies to.

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new database for each user, and you should also not create new tables for each user. You should have a fixed set of tables shared by all the users. For example:

- User: ID, login, first name, last name
- Forum: ID, name
- Post: ID, forum_id (FK to Forum.id), author_id (FK to User.ID), parent_post_id (FK to Post.ID), date, subject, body